# Automatically append capture=hbox in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to append the key `hbox` to all my `tcolorbox`es.

I was unsuccesful doing so by including it in my `tcbset`, so what other options do I have at my disposal for getting it done?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RCqybV8.png?1]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{capture=hbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Why does this stretch across \verb|\linewidth|. :-(
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox]
Correct result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `capture` mode is specifically protected against global changes by `\tcbset`.

@Andrew suggests the same thing I also would: one should use a custom `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{capture=hbox,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
This is some text in a box
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
Correct result
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

If you really, *really*, **really** want to change the capture mode, you could do so by the following code.

> The following code is just for demonstration. It uses internal undocumented macros which may change without notice in future versions. Also, globally setting `capture=hbox` is discouraged by principle.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\tcbset@late@options{capture=hbox}% you are discouraged to use this code
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is some text in a box
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Correct result
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is setting `capture=hbox` globally discouraged? Could you explain (by example or otherwise) how it could harm the output?

Comment: @1010011010 It's not really a matter of harm but more of concept. The capture modes stand for the distinct box types: `minipage` is the mode for `tcolorbox` and `hbox` is the mode for `\tcbox`. So, when using a `tcolorbox` without parameter, the normal minipage mode is/should be expected. I think I also had a technical reason for the restriction, but I don't remember exactly a critical example.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `\newtcolorbox` to define a custom tcolorbox that has `hbox` set by default:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{hbox,#1}% allow user to add custom options, with hbox as default
\begin{document}
  \begin{mybox}
    Why does this stretch across \verb|\linewidth|. :-(
  \end{mybox}
  \begin{mybox}[hbox]
  Correct result
  \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Using the new tcolorbox gives what you want:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but as you can see, `\verb` suddenly produces only a bar.